# Show different header names in 2 tables that share the same data model?

Tags: qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have 2 different tables that are based in the same data model. Their contents are generated with their own QSortFilterProxyModel, based on the same data model. The issue is that I can't give them different header names. In the following example both tables with have the name **Table2**. What can I do to allow them showing different header names?

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel();

QSortFilterProxyModel* proxyModel1 = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel1->setSourceModel(model);
proxyModel1->setHeaderData(0,  Qt::Horizontal, "Table1");


QSortFilterProxyModel* proxyModel2 = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel2->setSourceModel(model);
proxyModel2->setHeaderData(0,  Qt::Horizontal, "Table2");
```

Comment: I think it's impossible, because the header data shared between two views with a single model and the model doesn't know which view it supplies data to. You should use rather two instances of the same model.

Comment: Note that `QAbstractItemModel::headerData` and `setHeaderData` are both virtual so you could create your own proxy model that inherits from `QSortFilterProxyModel` and sets/gets the data itself rather than simply delegating the requests down to the source model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment you could have something like the following bare-bones example...

```
class proxy_model: public QSortFilterProxyModel {
  using super = QSortFilterProxyModel;
public:
  explicit proxy_model (QObject *parent = nullptr)
    : super(parent)
    {}
  virtual QVariant headerData (int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
        if (section == 0 && orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        {
            return m_data.at(section).at(orientation).at(role);
        }
        else
        {
            return super::headerData(section, orientation, role);
        }
    }
  virtual bool setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override
    {
      m_data[section][orientation][role] = value;
      return true;
    }
private:
  std::map<int/* section */, std::map<Qt::Orientation/* orientation */, std::map<int/* role */, QVariant>>> m_data;
};
```

Then your code becomes (untested)...

```
auto *model = new QStandardItemModel;

auto*proxyModel1 = new proxy_model(this);
proxyModel1->setSourceModel(model);
proxyModel1->setHeaderData(0,  Qt::Horizontal, "Table1");


auto *proxyModel2 = new proxy_model(this);
proxyModel2->setSourceModel(model);
proxyModel2->setHeaderData(0,  Qt::Horizontal, "Table2");
```